# How to get the basic range of an array?

Tags: arrays, range

How do you get the range of a basic array? New to coding and my teacher reads off of a script so I'm basically on my own. I need to find the max and minimum of the range and use those to find the range. Sorry if the question is bare bones, just in need of some help. If you want to view the assignment specifically it is 5.3.13 Most Improved on CodeHS.

Comment: Depends on the programming language. Just google something like "javascript array max" or "python list max" depending on the language you are learning and you will get a bunch of hits.

Comment: What language are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

use import java.util.*; and Arrays.sort(nameOfArray) to sort the elements in increasing order then return exams[nameOfArray.length - 1] - exams[0];

Answer (score 0):

Do this at the very top.

```
 import java.util.*;
```

Then this in getExamRange:

```
 Arrays.sort(exams);
 return exams[exams.length - 1] - exams[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get a range to calculate min and max of range in an array. All you need to do is start and finish on the right spots.

Pretty much any language will have a `for` loop and that's what you need.

```
for(int i = rangeStart; i < rangeEnd; i++) // maybe <= instead of < :)
{
  ...
}
```